# response-gating next message send, with Rx

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, blocking

given a `List<Message>` i send out the first message with my `Send(message)`. Now I would like to wait for (an asynchronous) response to come back before i send out the next message...

### Block until notified 'old' way

i know how to implement an event-based solution for this situation, using thread locking / with `Monitor.Wait` and  `Monitor.Pulse`

### Reactive 'new' way?

But I was wondering whether it would **make sense** to utilize [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) here?

If Rx would convey worthwhile benefits here then **how** could I make the response reactively gate the next send invocation? Obviously it would involve `IObservable`, probably two as primary sources, but then what?

Comment: Can you show more of your existing method signatures? Rx can be a good fit, but how it's done can depend on your starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very specific and seems to be very general in the sense that you have not mentioned what is the sender receiver etc, so the answer would also be very general :)

```
var receiveObs = //You have created a observable around the receive mechanism 
var responses = messages.Select(m => {
   send(m);
   return receiveObs.First();
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want, i expanded on it to get some test output, here is the first part of the simulation: `var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            var messages = (new[] { 1, 2, 3 }).ToObservable().Timestamp();
            var receiveObs = Observable.Generate(1, i => i < 4, i => i + 1, i => "answer" + i.ToString(), i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Timestamp();

            receiveObs.Subscribe(resp => Console.WriteLine(resp.Timestamp.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds + "sec <- Received " + resp.Value));`

Comment: and here is the business end: `var iterations = messages.Select(m =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Timestamp.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds + "sec -> Sent message" + m.Value);
                receiveObs.First();
                return m.Value;
            }).Timestamp();
            iterations.Subscribe(time => Console.WriteLine(time.Timestamp.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds + "sec handling " + time.Value + " finished"));`

Comment: and finally the console output: `0.109sec -> Sent message1
            2.112sec <- Received answer1
            2.126sec handling 1 finished
            2.13sec -> Sent message2
            4.12sec <- Received answer2
            4.135sec handling 2 finished
            4.135sec -> Sent message3
            6.132sec <- Received answer3
            6.147sec handling 3 finished`

Comment: this wont work, see Enigmativity comments: "You do realize that every time you call receiveObs.First() you are starting the observable again from the beginning? Your receiveObs observable is "cold". You don't share the observable - you're create four instances of it."

Comment: Yes, if receiveObs is cold observable then it wont work, but nowhere you have mentioned that your observable is cold.

Comment: Actually, Im using `Subject<>`, is it hot or cold? [`Subject<int> _myObservable = new Subject<int>(); _myObservable.OnNext(someImportantNumber);`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521254/new-data-to-observable-with-each-method-invocation)

Comment: tried it out with Subject<> and it seems hot! and could be made to work with cold observables as per Enigmativity comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think Rx is a good choice here, but I think I could be missing something in your requirements. From what I understand Rx provides a very simple solution.

If you already have a list of messages then you can send them reactively like so:

```
messages
    .ToObservable()
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
    .Subscribe(m =>
    {
        Send(m);
    });
```

This pushes the calls to `Send` to the thread-pool and, by the built-in behaviour of observables, each call to `Send` waits until the previous call is completed.

Since this is all happening on a different thread your code is non-blocking.

The extra benefit of Rx is that you wouldn't need to change the behaviour or signature of your `Send` method to make this work.

Simple, huh?

I tested this and it worked fine given my understanding of your problem. Is this all you need or is there something I missed?

Comment: sorry for being opaque about the requirements, the Send method is separate from a Receive callback, so Send will finish before the response is back; i.e. this code does not seem to achieve the gating desired

Comment: @Cel - can you tell me what it isn't doing that you need?

Comment: in short, there is no receiveObs invovled, as there is in the accepted answer for this post. I believe that the code in the comments for Ankur's answer behaves differently than your suggestion.

Comment: @Cel - I'd take another look at Ankur's answer and the code in the comments if I were you. The `receiveObs` isn't doing anything more than `Thread.Sleep(2000)`. You subscribe to it before your `messages.Select` query which instantiates a new observable - and this one doesn't affect your messages in any way. Then inside your `messages.Select` you create three more instances of the `receiveObs` each time you call `.First()`. It takes two seconds for the first `OnNext` to come back each time so it's just `Thread.Sleep(2000)`. Your code is also blocking on the main thread.

Comment: @Cel - if put in an `ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)` then your code won't block on the main thread - and since `receiveObs` isn't doing anything more than slowing your code down you might as well take that out.

Comment: the `Thread.Sleep(2000)` just emulates a real receiveObs, which is actually a critical response callback that takes some unpredicateble time to be received. the main focus of this post was to use this receiveObs as the gatekeeper. the additional `receiveObs` subscription was used to display text in the Console (for illustration and testing). thanks for pointing out the main thread blocking, which was not dealt with thus far.

Comment: @Cel - You do realize that every time you call `receiveObs.First()` you are starting the observable again from the beginning? It is totally predictable when it will fire - that's why I said it was the equivalent of `Thread.Sleep(2000)`. It is exactly that. Your `receiveObs` observable is "cold". You don't share the observable - you're create four instances of it.

Comment: i did not realize that about .First(), thanks for that! is there a way to share it / make it hot such that every subsequent call would return the next in line rather than start again? sorry for missing your point!

Comment: @Cel - It's not just `.First()`, it's anything that subscribes to the observable. You can use `.Publish()` to make a cold observable hot. I prefer using this syntax: `receiveObs.Publish(ros => { /* do shared stuff with ros here } )`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Rx is a good fit here. Rx is based on the concept of "push collections", i.e. pushing data to consumers instead of pulling it. What you want is pull the first item, send it asynchronously, and continue with the next element when the asynchronous operation finished. For this kind of job, the perfect tool would be **async** / **await***!

```
async void SendMessages(List<Message> messages)
{
    foreach (Message message in messages)
    {
        await SendAsync(message);
    }
}
```

with

```
Task SendAsync(Message message);
```

* *available in the Async CTP or the .NET 4.5 Preview*

Comment: What is the difference between a push collection and a sequence of asynchronous values?

Comment: i would really like to choose your response as an answer as well, but given Ankur answered with a fitting Rx solution, it took priority. Thanks heaps for making me aware of Async CTP though!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Send` method follows the APM model, the following approach should work for you

```
List<Message> messages;
IObservable<Response> xs;
xs =  messages.ToObservable().SelectMany(msg => Observable.FromAsyncPattern(Send, msg));
```

Edit - this won't work as Anderson has suggested, here's an example showing the problem

```
Func<int,string> Send = (ii) => { "in Send".Dump(); Thread.Sleep(2000); return ii.ToString(); };
Func<int,IObservable<string>> sendIO =  Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int,string>(Send.BeginInvoke, Send.EndInvoke);
(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }).ToObservable().SelectMany(sendIO).Dump();
```

Comment: Won't each message get processed at the same time (depending on the scheduler)? He seems to want them processed one at a time in order.

Comment: One at a time is the default behavior. Here's a snipit `(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }).ToObservable().SelectMany(ii => Observable.Return(ii).Do(dii => { "in async Call".Dump(); Thread.Sleep(5000);}))`

Comment: Must be something I'm missing. When I try this but have the second observable itself take a long time (rather than a Do on the observable) all of them finish at once. Rather than `Observable.Return`, try `Observable.Start(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return ii; } )` Note: I'm asking really because I'm missing something, not because I think you are wrong.