# new data to observable with each method invocation

Tags: c#, system.reactive

this may be really simple to those in the know-how, but how can i **directly** provide new data to a given observable, whenever a method of mine is invoked?

```
    IObservable<int> _myObservable; 

    void ThingsCallMe(int someImportantNumber)
    {
        // Current pseudo-code seeking to be replaced with something that would compile?
        _myObservable.Add(someImportantNumber);
    }

    void ISpyOnThings()
    {
        _myObservable.Subscribe(
            i =>
            Console.WriteLine("stole your number " + i.ToString()));
    }
```

i also dont know what kind of observable i should employ, one that gets to OnCompleted() under special circumstances only?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "one that gets to OnCompleted() under special circumstances only"? All observables follow the contract "OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)". Some just may not ever complete. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @Enigmativity please see Andersons answer, that was exactly what was desired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic answer. I modified your code slightly.

```
Subject<int> _myObservable = new Subject<int>(); 

void ThingsCallMe(int someImportantNumber)
{
    // Current pseudo-code seeking to be replaced with something that would compile?
    _myObservable.OnNext(someImportantNumber);
}

void ISpyOnThings()
{
    _myObservable.Subscribe(
        i =>
        Console.WriteLine("stole your number " + i.ToString()));
}
```

This should work. A subject is simply an IObservable and an IObserver. You can call OnCompleted, OnError, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and got this working:

```
static ObservableCollection<int> myCol = new ObservableCollection<int>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ((INotifyCollectionChanged)myCol).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Program_CollectionChanged);

  ThingsCallMe(4);
  ThingsCallMe(14);
}

static void ThingsCallMe(int someImportantNumber)
{
    myCol.Add(someImportantNumber);
}

static void Program_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.NewItems.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking about `IObservable` and not `ObservableCollection`. They are different.

Comment: Sorry, i should have made it clearer outside the tag taht the questions is about [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)